# Calculating total value of changed coins in sys.argv module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I have an issue in returning the total value of coins in Dollars using sys.argv module using Pycharm in Python running the code from Command prompt. User passes arguments (number of coins - 9 quarters, 7 dimes, 3 nickels, and 6 pennies) from command line. The sum supposed to return in Dollars, but my code does not return sum, repeats the arguments instead. Here is the code:

```py
import sys
sum = 0
for i in range(1,5):
    sum = int((sys.argv[1]) * 2 + (sys.argv[2]) * 3 + (sys.argv[3]) * 4 + (sys.argv[4]) * 5)
print('Result: ', sum)
```

The error in Command prompt is:

```
(base) E:\>python egg.py 9 7 3 6
Result:  99999999999999999999999997777777777333336
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that sys.argv stores all arguments as strings. When multiplying strings in python, it copies the string to the specified number. The actual solution should look like this:

```
sum = int(sys.argv[1]) * 2 + int(sys.argv[2]) * 3 + int(sys.argv[3]) * 4 + int(sys.argv[4]) * 5
```

This converts the variable to integers before multiplying them which should yield the right answer.

Comment: It worked. Both thumbs up. Thanks a much.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer to confirm the problem is solved and close the question